# why is code falling on substringwithrange

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

hi here is my function, but everytime when i try to init and alloc `foo` it falls, can you tell me why?

```
   -(NSString*)modifyTheCode:(NSString*) theCode{
        if ([[theCode substringToIndex:1]isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            if ([theCode length] == 1 ) {
            return @"0000000000";
        } 
            NSString* foo = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[theCode substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, [theCode length]-1)]];

            return [self modifyTheCode:foo];

        } else {

            return theCode;

        }


}
```

the error message:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
NSString* foo = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[theCode substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, [theCode length]-1)]];
```

with this line

```
NSString* foo = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[theCode substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [theCode length]-1)]];
```

and try..

Comment: it will delete the first or last character?for example what should it add for this string "0abba"?

Comment: nope..index starts from 0..Say you have a string of 5 characters, so range index is 0 to 4, substringWithRange should get string from index 1 to 4, right...

Comment: If you starts from index 2 and give [string length] - 1, you are asking to get 4 characters from index 2, which should be 2,3,4,5..

Comment: Sadly there is no characted at index 5..I think that is the reason of the crash..

Answer (score 1):

What is the error message?
If you are working with NSRange maybe you should check the length of theCode first.

Comment: it falls even the first time when the length is 10 characters

Answer (score 1):

Because the range is invalid.  NSRange has two members, location and length. The range you give starts at the **third** character of the string and has the length of the string minus one.  So your length is one character longer than the amount of characters left in the string.

Suppose theCode is `@"0123"`.  The range you create is `{ .location = 2, .length = 3 }`  This represents:

```
0123
  ^ start of range is here
     ^ start of range + 3 off the end of the string.
```

By the way, you'll be pleased to know that there are convenience methods so you don't have to mess with ranges.  You could do:

```
if ([theCode hasPrefix: @"0"])
{

    NSString* foo = [theCode substringFromIndex: 1]; // assumes you just want to strip off the leading @"0"

    return [self modifyTheCode:foo];

} else {

    return theCode;

}
```

By the way, your original code leaked `foo` because you never released it.